# How to run simple javascript code in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I want to write a simple script for private use that receives a string (in a text box), manipulates it (in a way that I decide) and prints it as a text block. I wonder how to integrate this with Chrome. Should I write a Chrome extension for this? Or is there a simpler tool that allows me to run this script upon clicking it from the bookmarks bar?

Comment: use the console , write your script ; then in chrome click f12 button , paste and test your code

Comment: Or make the text a cli arg to a node.js script running in a terminal.

Comment: @SpringerF How does this address my need to run the script from the bookmarks bar?

Comment: for bookmark add bookmark name it , and in url  just start with `javascript:(function(){ content of your function ...})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's called a *bookmarklet*.

Make a bookmark, click edit, and set the url to `javascript:` followed by the code you wish to execute. That's all.

Comment: Thank you! Looks very simple. Is there an option to present an HTML with a bookmarklet, with a button of submission of the string and a text block for presenting the output?

Comment: I think the most quick-and-dirty solution would be to use `prompt`. First to prompt for input, then to use as a means of providing a text box which could be easily copied from. If you wanted a bookmarklet to take a text and make it uppercase: `javascript:var a=prompt('provide text:'); if(!!a) prompt('result', a.toUpperCase());`. If you want more advanced forms, you'd have to create elements and insert into the dom manually.